# Looking for cat sounds [request]

Tags: request

Hey all,

Just wondering if anyone had a couple cat hissing sounds laying around that I could experiment with.  Trying to sweeten some vampire attacks,  have not really played much with animal vocalizations so Im not sure if I am even in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The 30 free downloads from my blog were all snatched up a while ago, but here is a link where another thirty people can grab the sounds.

You can read how how I recorded the sounds at the link in Justin Huss' answer, or here: http://www.azimuthaudio.ca/azimuth-blog/2011/5/11/cringer-the-cat-attack.html

Sadly Cringer the cat has past away in the last month.  So these recordings are my way of keeping the angry little guy around.  They are free to use anyway you please.

1. File: Cringer Masters.zip

   ### Link: https://www2.ibackup.com/qmanager/servlet/share?key=ibome65054

Comment: @AzimuthAudio  Thanks a bunch, I saw this while searching earlier but all the downloads had been used.

Comment: No problem.  Hope they work out for you.  If you end up using them let me know what the project is so I can keep an ear out for it.

Answer (score 2):

I remember [@AzimuthAudio's blog](http://www.azimuthaudio.ca/azimuth-blog/2011/5/11/cringer-the-cat-attack.html) offered 30 free downloads of a cat library he created with quite awesome cat sounds (Mr Cringer it was named). Maybe you could try and contact him...

Answer (score 1):

Hey Michael,

I don't know much about your project, but for something like this I might even try just using your mouth. At least that way you'll have a better feel for if you need cat hisses or not. As vampires are kinda demi-human anyways, I don't think any layer that sounds more like you than a cat would be a big problem.

Food for thought!

Comment: @Luca My own vocalizations are probably going to be what makes it in, but while I have time to play before picture gets to me I am doing some experiments.  I only plan on using hissing or something of that nature when fangs are exposed or attacking.  
Figured I would ask before I pissed off cats to record them, I am also highly allergic to cats so they win every time.